# JavaFx WebView component on Android

Tags: android, webview, javafx

I heard about the possibility of launching JavaFx projects on Android.

So, is it possible to use powerful JavaFx WebView component instead of Android WebView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently (and surprisingly to me), it looks like you can make use of the JavaFX WebView API from an Android (or iOS) application.

[JavaFXPorts includes some documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/) which [links to some sample projects](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/tip?at=default), one of which is titled webdemo and demonstrates use of the WebView API from a ported environment (such as Android or iOS).

- Link to [webdemo source](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src/tip/WebDemo/src/main/java/org/javafxports/webdemo/Main.java?fileviewer=file-view-default).

I encourage you to follow the JavaFXPorts documentation to build and deploy the webdemo project.  I have not tried this myself.

*Some background and suppositions*

I do not know what the underlying implementation of the WebView is in the ported environment.  For a desktop environment, Oracle maintain a modified branch of the webkit code that is used as the underlying implementation for the WebEngine of the WebView.  This modified implementation uses the JavaFX toolkit for all rendering operations, so that unstyled UI elements such as buttons and choice boxes look the same in JavaFX in the embedded WebView.  The modified implementation also uses Java networking code rather than WebKit networking code and probably has numerous other modifications.

My guess is that in the port code, that the modified WebKit codebase from the desktop system is not used, but instead the WebKit implementations that ship with Android and iOS are used via their APIs (but this is a guess and I do not know).  Regardless, from a developer point of view, it would seem that the actual implementation can be ignored and you can get an embedded web browser using the WebView API that is built into JavaFX.  That makes your code easily portable and executable on different environments.  You, as an application developer, don't have to code directly to an iOS or Android embedded web browser API, but can just stick with the cross-platform Java API (which, hopefully, provides all the functionality you need).